# Insert record in table if does not exist in iPhone app

Tags: iphone, ios, json, sqlite

I am obtaining a json array from a url and inserting data into a table. Since the contents of the url are subject to change, I want to make a second connection to a url and check for updates and insert new records in y table using sqlite3.

The issues that I face are:

1) My table doesn't have a primary key

2) The url lists the changes on the same day. Hence, if I run my app multiple times, when I insert values in my database, I get duplicate entries. I want to keep a check for the day duplicated entries that should be removed. The problem can be solved by adding a constraint, but since the url itself has duplicated values, I find it difficult.

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can see you can do it if you have no primary key or something you can use that is unique to each record, is when you get your new data in you go through the new entries where for each one you check if the exact same data exists in the database already. If it doesn't then you add it, if it does then you skip over it.

You could even do something like create a unique key yourself for each entry which is a concatenation of each column of the table. That way you can quickly do the check for if the entry already exists in the database.

Answer (score 0):

I see two possibilities depending on your setup:

1. You have a column setup as UNIQUE (this can be through a PRIMARY KEY or not). In this case, you can use the ON CONFLICT clause:

   http://www.sqlite.org/lang_conflict.html

   If you find this construct a little confusing, you can instead use "INSERT OR REPLACE" or "INSERT OR IGNORE" as described here:

   http://www.sqlite.org/lang_insert.html
2. You do not have a column setup as UNIQUE. In this case, you will need to SELECT first to verify for duplicate data, and based on the result INSERT, UPDATE, or do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

A more common & robust way to handle this is to associate a timestamp with each data item on the server.  When your app interrogates the server it provides the timestamp corresponding to the last time it synced.  The server then queries its database and returns all values that are timestamped later than the timestamp provided by the app.  Then it also returns a new timestamp value for the app to store, to use on the next sync.